# Change content pane of JFrame and new component not displaying

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game and I'm trying to switch between different `JPanel`s to display the menu, world etc.

```
public static void setComponent(Component component){
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.getContentPane().add(component, 0);   
    }
```

This is the method to change the component of the `JFrame` frame, this works for the first time with whichever `JPanel` component I give it, but when I try to change it from inside any class from a keyListener method say, the content pane doesn't display anything.

```
@Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Frame.setComponent(new MenuPanel());
        }
```

Method to create the `JFrame` and the thread that repaints the components

```
public static void createFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(frame.getComponentCount() != 0){
                    //System.out.println("?");
                    frame.getContentPane().repaint();   
                    System.out.println(frame.getContentPane().getComponentAt(1, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

    setComponent(new MenuPanel());  

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Getting this result from the Output Stream when first loading

```
Menu.MenuPanel[,0,0,794x571,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Then after using the `setComponent` method from another class

```
javax.swing.JPanel[null.contentPane,0,0,794x571,invalid,layout=java.awt.GridLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Comment: Create a main JPanel and put the components on the JPanel, rather than the content pane of the JFrame.  Using a CardLayout makes switching JPanels much easier.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: In the past I've ended up with very messy paintComponent methods for the JPanel trying to decide which part to draw, I'll take a look at cardLayout

Answer (score 1):

When you call your `setComponent` method the first time, you do that before you call `frame.setVisible(true)` that forces the frame to validate all its components and show them.
When you change the components later you need to revalidate your frame manually so it gets aware of its components. Add these lines to your `setComponent` method and it should work.

```
public static void setComponent(Component component){
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(component, 0);
    frame.revalidate();   // revalidate all the frame components
    frame.repaint();      // and repaint the frame
}
```